# Good java annotations for "human name" (non english)

Tags: java, jpa, internationalization, annotations

I use extensively JPA annotations over class (entities, fields too) for "technical" purposes, and for automatic works with GUI, ad-hoc reports "human friendly" other annotations.
I older project totally "home made", maybe in new projects should I override from some ready standard annotation?

Polish language has higher requirements than English, not only singular/plural like few English solutions, but declinations too (partially implemented in software), and has additional letters (prohibited in elements of java language, C# allow)

```
@Entity(name = "Kontrahent")
@ClassCaption("Kontraheci") -> plural from Kontrahent
..
public class Kontrahent extends {
}
```

Imagination of future solution:

```
// transaltion: Fixed Assets
@XxxxxCaption(aaaa="Środek Trwały", bbb="Środki Trwałe", softwarename="SrodekTrwaly")
@Entity ST {
   @Column(length=24)
   @XxxxxCaption(xxLong="Numer środka Trwałego", xxxShort="Numer ST")
   String No;
}
```

What family of Java annotations can be base for me?

*(formal: if someone sees strange letters, don't worry)*

Comment: Sarcastic from author: I know, software things (entities) **should be named in English**, ie FixedAssets not SrodkiTrwale, but how to say in fluent english "urlop maciezyński dla ojca" (mothers leave optional for father) and distinct it from "ojcowskie" (additional few days leave only for father new born child). Kodeks Pracy (Act for Workers) has +/- 70years, 30000paragr, few thaus, of updates, I suppose nobody of native Pole fully understand, how to translate to english? Few day ago Partalment want help small shops, but m. mistake in Act <400m2 and >400m2. Nobody in Parliament was programmer?